# How to modify the one2many or many2one field in other model odoo10

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10

Can any one tell with example **how to modify the field in another model if changed in type-one2many field.**

For example, I have two models a) hr_shifts b)hr_contract
in hr_shifts there is one2many field(emp_name_ids) when changed in this fields reflect in hr_contract after click on save button.
this code work, but **when I used in one2many field (emp_name_ids) it doesn't work**

```
@api.depends('schedule')
    def _onchange_schedule(self):
        for item in self.hr_shifts_line:
        current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)])
        current.write({'working_hours':self.schedule.id})
```

Comment: please indent your code.

Comment: @api.depends('hr_shifts_line.emp_name_ids')
 def _depends_emp_name_ids(self):
  print "::::::::::::" 
  for item in self.hr_shifts_line:
     
   print ":::::::mmmm::"
   current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)])
   print current,"::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
   current.write({'employee_id':self.emp_name_ids.id})

Answer (score 0):

`One2many` and `Many2many` use a special "commands" format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field.

You should try:

```
current.write({'emp_name_ids': [(6, 0, [ids])]})
```

For more info regarding the special commands see docs: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#model-reference.

Scroll a bit down to the CRUD section there you will find all possible commands (`(6, _, ids)` is only one of a few more).

Comment: i want to write the name of employee not working hours.. to write the working_hours i already use the above code. how to update the employee name. i tried the following code:                          @api.depends('hr_shifts_line.emp_name_ids')
 def _depends_emp_name_ids(self):
  print "::::::::::::" 
  for item in self.hr_shifts_line:
     
   print ":::::::mmmm::"
   current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)])
   print current,"::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"

Comment: I edited my comment. Use `emp_name_ids` instead and link it to the corresponding ids. The point of my answer is, that you need to use the right command for One2many fields. Which you don't do according to all your code examples. Have you looked into the documentation?

Comment: ya i used but it doesn't work. what i am tried :-                                             @api.depends('hr_shifts_line.emp_name_ids')
 def _depends_emp_name_ids(self):
  print "::::::::::::" 
  for item in self.hr_shifts_line:
   print ":::::::mmmm::"
current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)])
   print current,"::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
   current.write({'employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id})
   # current.update({'employee_id': [(6,0,[self.emp_name_ids.id])]})

Comment: `self.emp_name_ids.id` does this return a list of ids or a single id?